# Saleor optional Apps

Tags: saleor

There are optional apps on shopify that is necessary. 
1. abandoned cart - these apps do additional follow up with 'customers' by sending a number of emails (can chose how many mails) to chase up on purchase.
2. a floating sticky cart
3. tracking parcels
4. photo reviews
5. multi currency
6. sms message on status
7. upselling apps - these apps may give quantity discounts, or after checkout push u to buy another piece at a discount.

Are there functionalities like these in Saleor?

I was trying to get your dash board demo but could not register. message: 
BE AWARE PIRATE!
SALEOR RUNS IN READ ONLY MODE!

If saleor team can share with me will be great.

Comment: I don't think so that saleor provides such features at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Having those apps would be great, perhaps the can be added as features in the future.

I believe that testing out the dashboard is possible by going to:

> "https://pwa.saleor.io/dashboard/"

And login in with the following credentials:

> **username:** admin@example.com
>
> **password:** admin